# Custom Table SQL Server IF i have Final Result Like This

Tags: sql, distinct

I'm Noob, I want Ask SQL Database Query. If I have Table Like This :

```
CREATE TABLE Test
( 
     ID   int IDENTITY(1,1),
     NAMA VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     DETAIL VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
);
```

And I fill my table like this :

[image: Image 1 (Data Table)]

and i want make that Table (Table i fill before) Like This :

[image: Image 2 (Result Like This)]

Did you know Query for make my Table Like That?

i try it before but result not same With Image 2 (Result) This my code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.NAMA AS MIS, a2.NAMA AS FINANCE, a3.NAMA AS PURCHASING 
FROM TEST a1, Test a2,Test a3 
WHERE a1.Detail = 'MIS' AND a2.DETAIL = 'FINANCE' AND a3.DETAIL='PURCHASING' 
GROUP BY a1.NAMA, a2.NAMA, a3.NAMA
```

Can anyone help me to fix my query?
Use SQL SERVER 2008.

Comment: Can you please put images in question itself?

Comment: What server are you using MS SQL, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: @AK47: That would be hard for a 1 rep user.

Comment: @idstam: ASK. Never heard of it.

Comment: Images should only be used for support, and are in fact not at all needed here. Include a small repro instead, with some DDL and a few inserts for sample data. This would trump images anytime, making the question better for SEO, easier to read, and more helpful to others with similar problems.

Comment: Using PIVOT table is the best for your question

Comment: How will you decide `Herdyawan`,`Suandi`,`Iren` will come in first row?

Comment: Don't mix DISTINCT with GROUP BY!!! DISTINCT is pretty much the same as GROUP BY, but used when no aggregate functions (e.g. SUM, MAX, MIN) are involved.

Answer (score 0):

IN T-SQL you can write a query as:

```
;WITH CTEMIS AS (
SELECT a1.NAMA AS MIS,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  a1.Detail ORDER BY a1.Id asc) AS rownum    
FROM @TEST a1 
WHERE a1.Detail = 'MIS'
),CTEFINANCE as
(
SELECT a1.NAMA AS FINANCE,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  a1.Detail ORDER BY a1.Id asc) AS rownum    
FROM @TEST a1 
WHERE a1.Detail = 'FINANCE'
),CTEPURCHASING as
(
SELECT a1.NAMA AS PURCHASING,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  a1.Detail ORDER BY a1.Id asc) AS rownum    
FROM @TEST a1 
WHERE a1.Detail = 'PURCHASING'
)
SELECT MIS ,FINANCE,PURCHASING
FROM CTEMIS 
FULL JOIN CTEFINANCE ON CTEMIS.rownum = CTEFINANCE.rownum
FULL JOIN CTEPURCHASING ON CTEFINANCE.rownum = CTEPURCHASING.rownum
```